# Issue while handling database connection in Multi-threaded Server - Java

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, spring-jdbc

I have created a Java based server which will listen for data from clients. 
As the server receives data , it has to parse it & update it in Database. 
Client sends data very frequently say every 2-3 seconds &  number of clients can be from 200-1000. 
What I have done is Server is Continuously listening for data from client. 
As it receives data, it starts a new thread(will be separate thread for each client) which parses data & updates it in database.
I am using only one connection with database for updating information of each client.
Issue is sometimes previous request is not completed  & another request is sent by client which go on increases for  other clients also as I am using same database  connection for all clients.

I need suggestion to improve performance that whether I should create separate connection for each client  OR else what should I do ?

Editted :- 
Anybody please help with the code. 
Say If I am dealing with the 600-700 client sending data & creating separate thread for each client upon request & then breaking it .then what should be my database  pool size ?.
More threads are also running parallel  which makes connection with database. May I need to wait If client data is  being processed. But In my case I can not hold client data. How do I handle this?
Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Create a pool of connections beforehand. Whenever a new request comes, provide a connection that is free, to that request. This way, you will not be connecting/disconnecting dynamically, and still get a connection availability.

Comment: Make sure you understand the workings of the connection pool you choose. A badly configured connection pool can be almost as bad as no connection pool at all.

Comment: Or were you suggesting that he writes the pooling functionality himself? I hope not.

Comment: Connection pools tend to be database independent, so there's no reason to attempt to write your own.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use poolable connections for database and a thread pool to go with it.

For poolable connection you can use [Apache DBCP](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/download_dbcp.cgi), check out [configuration options](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/configuration.html)
Below is example usage

```
BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
ds.setDriverClassName(JDBCDriver);
ds.setUrl(JDBCUrl);
ds.setUsername(JDBCUser);
ds.setPassword(JDBCPassword);
ds.setInitialSize(initSize);
ds.setMaxTotal(maxTotal);//negative for no limit
ds.setTestOnBorrow(false);
ds.setTestWhileIdle(true);

Connection con = ds.getConnection();
```

For thread pool you can use [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html)

It has following methods

```
execute(Runnable)
submit(Runnable)
submit(Callable)
invokeAny(...)
invokeAll(...)
```

Following is sample usage

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Asynchronous task");
    }
});
```

Now no matter how many Runnables are submitted to ExecutorService it runs only 10 at a time.